# What is a good framework for using web-view like tabs for native applications?

Tags: iphone, tabs, webview

I would like to implement web-view like tabs in a native iPhone application. I would prefer not to write it from scratch. Is there a framework I can use for this feature? Here is an example.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's Guidelines would tell you to use a Tab Bar placed at the bottom for this. It's also possible to create upper "tabs" using a styled UISegmentedControl or just UIButton's that switches views.

Comment: I already use a tab bar at the bottom and a segmented control at the top. Segmented controls at the top is ugly. The same is true (ugly) for UIButtons. I am looking for something like the image that I've attached.

Comment: You can use images for UIButtons etc to create something well-styled. I've also dome some tricks in the past using 'UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled' as the style for a segmented control and placing it so that you don't see the edges of the control - it makes it look more tab-bar like.